# Compare two strings and generate a new string with components from both

Tags: php

I have a sting that looks like this

```
$storelist = "‘F Mart (6)’, ‘ACME (5)’, 'J/M Store (17)'";
```

I want to break out selected companies and the number of locations by comparing the first string to a second string like

```
$selectedstores = "‘F Mart’, 'J/M Store";
```

And output a sting like

```
$selectedwithnumber = "‘F Mart (6)’, 'J/M Store (17)'"
```

There could be 1 to 15 companies in a string and the location number varies but the apostrophes and parenthesis are standard. I hope there an easy way to do this as I have no idea where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to look at things if you converted your strings into arrays. [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) can help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use explode function to split arrays to parts, and use preg_replace function to remove number of companies (with brackets) from first string. below you can find working example:

```
$storelist = "‘F Mart (6)’, ‘ACME (5)’, 'J/M Store (17)'";
$selectedstores = "‘F Mart’, 'J/M Store'";

//split second array
$selectedArray = explode(', ', $selectedstores);

$resultArray = array();
//split first array
foreach(explode(', ', $storelist) as $storeWithNumber) {
  //remove " (number)" from each part
  $store = preg_replace('/\s+\(\d+\)/', '', $storeWithNumber);
  //check if current part is on selected list
  if (in_array($store, $selectedArray)) {
    $resultArray[] = $storeWithNumber;
  }
}

$selectedwithnumber = implode(', ', $resultArray);

echo $selectedwithnumber.PHP_EOL;
```

result is:

```
‘F Mart (6)’, 'J/M Store (17)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get what you need based on your description.  It breaks up your strings into arrays and then uses a nested `foreach` loop to do the comparisons.  I used string functions over regular expression functions in case speed becomes an issue.  It does however require that your main string of stores follows the conventions you described.

```
<?php

$storelist = "'F Mart (6)', 'ACME (5)', 'J/M Store (17)'";

$selectedstores = "'F Mart', 'J/M Store'";

$stores = explode(",", $storelist);

$selected = explode(",", $selectedstores);

$newStoreList = array();

foreach($selected as $selectedStore) {
    foreach($stores as $store) {
        $s = trim( $selectedStore, "' ");
        if(strstr($store, $s)) {
            $newStoreList[] = $store;
        }
    }
}


$newStoreList = implode(",", $newStoreList);

echo $newStoreList; 

?>
```

This will output: `'F Mart (6)', 'J/M Store (17)'`

Hope that helps!